# Fastest method of streaming csv formatted data from ChildStdout to File

Tags: optimization, rust, io, rust-tokio

I'm looking for ways to speed up writing data to a file, and I've tried several methods without much success.
Essentially the process is

- Spawn a child process that sends a request to BigQuery through the BQ
  CLI API.
- Stream data to a `MutexGuard<Box<dyn Write>>` using `std::io::copy`.

Here is a small reproduction of the code as I have it currently. This probably won't compile on its own, but I think it will be enough to explain what I'm doing in detail.

```rust
use std::process::{Command, ChildStdout, Child, Stdio};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write};
use std::sync::MutexGuard;
use std::box::Box;

const CAP: usize = 1024 * 8;

fn main() {
    let cmd = "bq --format csv query";
    let cmd = cmd.split_whitespace();
    let query = "path/to/query.sql"
    let (mut child, stdout) = spawn(cmd, query).await?

    let save_path = "path/to/save/file.csv"
    let file = File::open(save_path).unwrap();

    let mut rdr = BufReader::with_capacity(CAP, stdout);
    let wtr = Mutex::new(Box::new(BufWriter::with_capacity(CAP, file)));
    

    write(&mut child, &mut rdr, &wtr).unwrap();

}

fn create_cmd(args: Vec<&str>) -> Result<Command> {
    let mut v_itr = args.into_iter();
    let mut cmd = match v_itr.next() { 
        Some(s) => Command::new(which(s).unwrap()),
        None => return Err("Must supply at least one command argument.".into())
    };
    
    while let Some(s) = v_itr.next() {
        // This is essentially Vec's "push", but for adding arguments to a shell command.
        cmd.arg(s);
    };

    Ok(cmd)
}

fn spawn(cmd: Vec<u8>, query: &str) -> Result<ChildStdout> {
    let cmd = create_cmd(cmd)

    let query = std::fs::read_to_string(query).unwrap();
    let query = query.trim();
    cmd.arg(query);

    let mut child = match cmd
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
    {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
    };

    // Sleep while waiting for the child process to fully start,
    // otherwise we may get an error when getting a handle to stdout.
    let sleep_time = Duration::new(2, 0);
    sleep(sleep_time);

    Ok(child, stdout)
}

fn write<R: Read, W: Write>(child: &mut Child, rdr: &mut R, wtr: Mutex<Box<W>>) -> Result<()> {
    let mut wtr_lock = wtr.lock().unwrap();
    let mut wtr_ref = &mut *wtr_lock;

    while let Ok(None) = child.try_wait() {
        std::io::copy(rdr, wtr_ref).unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

So far I've tried:

- Using tokio equivalents of the std BufWriter and BufReader
- Not using any buffered input
- Using LineWriter for output
- Using buffered writing with no buffered reading
- Implementing an async equivalent of `stack_buffer_copy` from `std` but with Tokio (this was extremely slow - I basically copied almost word for word what was in std and then implemented BufMut for a struct that wrapped ReadBuf)

The data sizes I'm writing can really be anything up to a few GiB, but I'm not worried about speed for anything below 20 MiB. Currently, I get speeds of a little over 1 MiB/s, which is much slower than I want. I don't mind if the solution is complex, I just want to see what's possible (I'm mainly doing this as a learning opportunity).

As a side note, the response from BQ usually only takes about 5~10 seconds (the BQ command actually prints something like `Waiting on bqjob_**** ... (10s) Current status: DONE` to stderr) from start to finish, so I know that isn't a bottleneck in this case. The computer I'm using is a Mac M1 Air with 16GiB of RAM. I'm compiling using the following command: `RUSTFLAGS="--emit=asm" cargo build --release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do any processing of the data, I'd try to avoid piping and copying the data, and just let the child process write to that file directly.

So instead of this:

```
cmd.stdout(Stdio::piped())
```

you can pass your `file`:

```
cmd.stdout(file)
```

This should work, because `Stdio` implements `From<File>`. There's an example of this [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#examples-6) (although with stdin, not stdout).

To measure your baseline speed, you can run the command from the terminal:

```
$ bq ... > path/to/save/file.csv
```

Then you'd know what to expect in terms of speed.

P.S. If you are curious why your program is slow, try using [flamegraph](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested as you mentioned, and found that really I can't get much faster than I already had. In any case, I changed the program as you mentioned to reduce complexity. Thank you for the advice!